# I am trying to install gitlab omnibus packages on a ubuntu container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I lunched a container with

```
docker container run -it ubunutu
```

and run some commands :

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
apt-get install curl openssh-server ca-certificates
curl https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ce/script.deb.sh | bash
apt-get install gitlab-ce
```

until now it was all fine, but when I run `gitlabctl reconfigure`, It start and always stops in this step of installation `ruby_block[supervise_redis_sleep] action run`

Is there any solution to this problem??

I am using the latest version of ubuntu image, I also tried debian image. But all of them stop at that step!!

This is when I run apt-get `install gitlab-ce` , it was fine[image]

but now when I run `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` , it stops always here

[image]

```
ruby_block[supervise_redis_sleep] action run
```

Comment: Can you show us more verbose log output?

Comment: OK, no idea yet??

Comment: This problem seems to be described in the docs : https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/common_installation_problems/README.html#reconfigure-freezes-at-ruby_blocksupervise_redis_sleep-action-run   Can you try some of the suggestions here?

Comment: well, you can't use either of systemctl or initctl in a docker container!!!